# Text color changes after applying the alpha in Android

Tags: android, colors, transparency, alpha

I have a custom_row.xml which will become part of ListView using BaseAdapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="anyBackgroundColor(#HexValue)">

     inner content has text view of white color

  </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

After apply alpha property to RelativeLayout the text color becomes little faint.

[image]

I don't want the text to become faint and also achieve transparency on my background color which is not an image.
How we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you apply alpha to layout, you are effectively applying alpha on everything that layout contains. That is why your text has become partially transparent too.

Hex value of colors in Android is defined as `AARRGGBB` - alpha, red, green and blue. So changing `AA` (`00` - fully transparent, `FF` - opaque) part of color hex code will give your layout background color transparency, leaving other views it contains intact.

For instance

```
android:background="#66D500F9" -> alpha part is 66
```

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you for answer and explaination.

Comment: If above is not working then you will need to update your question and add   [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.